# How to use price range inside "Offer" type?

Tags: ecommerce, schema.org, microdata

I have category pages that contain products. Some of the products have fixed prices and some of the products have price ranges.

Also any product has a seller that must be inside `Offer`. Right? So I must use the `Offer` type and I can not using `PriceSpecification`. Am I wrong?

How can I use Microdata with this condition?

A product with price range in my product list page:

```html
<li  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"   >
<span  itemprop="name" >ProductName</span>

<div   itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

<ul>
 <li><meta itemprop="maxprice" content="1000000"  /><meta itemprop="minprice" content="10000"  />
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD"  />
from 10,000 to 1,000,000 USD</li>

</ul>

<div  itemprop="seller" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<ul>

<li><span itemprop="telephone" >00188341534</span></li>
</ul>
</div>

 <div  itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span  itemprop="addressLocality">Washington</span></div>
```

I need valid code look like this. But this code is not valid.

Comment: Your using a lot of bloat in your code... what's the point in using of `ul > li > meta` when just meta would do fine. Also, you could use 
`<li temprop="telephone">00188341534</li>`, only use spans and element elements for styling, or when you absolutely have no other choice. The examples on Schema, are purely for example purposes only. You can use itemtype and itemprop on all containers, such as `<main>`,  `<ul>`,`<header>`,`<body>`,`<html>`,`<h1>`,`<p>`,`<li>`,`<ul>`,`<section>` and so on.

Comment: @SimonHayter I am using meta because some data inside span is not valid for Microdata. So i have to use meta that is invisible to users.Am i right? But about using a lot of bloat, you are right.Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: I was referring to meta within a the UL, LI, its pointless since meta is not an element, or visible to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `PriceSpecification` for the `Offer`, by using the [`priceSpecification`](http://schema.org/priceSpecification) property:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <div itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
    </div>

  </div>

</article>
```

And inside the `PriceSpecification`, you can use the [`minPrice`](http://schema.org/minPrice) and [`maxPrice`](http://schema.org/maxPrice) properties. (Note that they are case-sensitive.)

Comment: Wow! itemprop "priceSpecification" is correct! Yes! not "PriceSpecification"

Answer (score -1):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

  <h1 itemprop="description">New furnace and installation</h1>

    <div itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
    Prices for a unit installation:<br>

    Minimum : <span itemprop="minPrice">10.00</span><span itemprop="priceCurrency">USD</span>
    <br>
    Maximum : <span itemprop="maxPrice">30.00</span><span itemprop="priceCurrency">USD</span>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: A code only answer is not high quality.   You should edit this answer and explain more about what the code does.   It would be helpful to link to any documentation about it as well.